# SQL Conditional update with case

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a conditional update of an ntext field. In one situation I want it to append to the field. In the other I want it to leave the field alone. The code is..

```
UPDATE CC
    SET Comm_Note = CASE DESC_REG WHEN NULL THEN COMM_NOTE ELSE rtrim(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),comm_note))+ 'Registration Issue: '+  LTRIM(DESC_REG) END
FROM 
    RAW_DATA RD
    INNER JOIN CONFIRMIT_COMMUNICATION CC ON CC.RESPONSEID = RD.RESPONSEID
```

so when the DESC_REG field is null it should basically leave the current value of the COMM_NOTE field in there, but when it's not null it should append to the field. The appending bit works, but when DESC_REG is null, then the code nulls out the COMM_NOTE field completely

help!

Answer (score 0):

There are **[two CASE expression formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)**.

You are using a Simple `CASE` expression, to deal with `Null` you need to change your `CASE` expression to a Searched `CASE` format:

```
UPDATE CC
SET Comm_Note = CASE WHEN DESC_REG Is NULL THEN Comm_Note
                 ELSE ... END
FROM ...
```

Simple CASE expression uses `=` operator which cannot be used to check `NULL` values because `NULL` is undefined in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE CC
    SET Comm_Note = CASE
                        WHEN DESC_REG IS NULL
                        THEN COMM_NOTE
                        ELSE rtrim(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),comm_note))+ 'Registration Issue: ' + LTRIM(DESC_REG)
                    END
FROM 
    RAW_DATA RD
    INNER JOIN CONFIRMIT_COMMUNICATION CC ON CC.RESPONSEID = RD.RESPONSEID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once,

```
UPDATE CC
    SET Comm_Note = CASE WHEN DESC_REG IS NULL THEN COMM_NOTE ELSE rtrim(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),comm_note))+ 'Registration Issue: '+  LTRIM(DESC_REG) END
FROM 
    RAW_DATA RD
    INNER JOIN CONFIRMIT_COMMUNICATION CC ON CC.RESPONSEID = RD.RESPONSEID
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of the [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). The first takes an argument immediately after the `CASE` keyword and the second doesn't. In the first form you can't compare to `NULL` but you can in the second. So you can do what you want by

```
UPDATE CC
    SET Comm_Note = CASE WHEN DESC_REG IS NULL THEN COMM_NOTE ELSE rtrim(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),comm_note))+ 'Registration Issue: '+  LTRIM(DESC_REG) END
FROM 
    RAW_DATA RD
    INNER JOIN CONFIRMIT_COMMUNICATION CC ON CC.RESPONSEID = RD.RESPONSEID
```

However, you probably should use a `WHERE` clause instead:

```
UPDATE CC
    SET Comm_Note = rtrim(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),comm_note))+ 'Registration Issue: '+  LTRIM(DESC_REG)
FROM 
    RAW_DATA RD
    INNER JOIN CONFIRMIT_COMMUNICATION CC ON CC.RESPONSEID = RD.RESPONSEID
WHERE DESC_REG IS NOT NULL
```